# How to update react context provider state on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

WebContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, Component } from 'react';

export const WebContext = createContext();

class WebContextProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        inputAmount: 1,
    };

    render() {
        return <WebContext.Provider value={{ ...this.state }}>{this.props.children}</WebContext.Provider>;
    }
}

export default WebContextProvider;
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {

return (
        <WebContextProvider>
            <UpdateBtn />
        </WebContextProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

UpdateBtn.js

```
const UpdateBtn = () => {

return (
        <Div>
            <Button onClick={} />
        </Div>
    );
};

export default UpdateBtn;
```

How do I update the **inputAmount** state present in **WebContext.js** on button click in **UpdateBtn.js**? **App.js** is the parent component for **UpdateBtn.js** Also, How can I convert the **WebContext.js** into a functional component?

Comment: There are perfect examples for this on the official React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the function in Provider which you can call to update the value: 
WebContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, Component } from 'react';

export const WebContext = createContext();

class WebContextProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        inputAmount: 1,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <WebContext.Provider
                value={{
                    data: ...this.state, // all data now in context.data field
                    update: () => { // we added this callback
                        this.setState((state) => ({
                            inputAmount: state.inputAmount + 1,
                        }));
                    },
                }}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </WebContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default WebContextProvider;
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {

return (
        <WebContextProvider>
            <UpdateBtn />
        </WebContextProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

UpdateBtn.js

```
const UpdateBtn = () => {
const context = useContext(WebContext); // we use hook to get context value
return (
        <Div>
            <Button onClick={context.update} /> 
        </Div>
    );
};

export default UpdateBtn;
```

or

```
const UpdateBtn = () => {

// or we can use Consumer to get context value
return (
        <Div>
            <WebContext.Consumer>
              {context => <Button onClick={context.update} />}
            </WebContext.Consumer>
        </Div>
    );
};

export default UpdateBtn;
```

Comment: Thanks. In this scenario, how can I call another function from update(), which is present parallel to update() in WebContextProvider?

Comment: If I recognized your question clearly, you can do similar like this: https://gist.github.com/xnimorz/8eb9b5aa4c1f3167601675b5c53d9b4f

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach might be to use a reducer to update your state. For example:

```
export const initialState = {
  inputValue: 1
}

export function reducer(state, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case 'updateInputValue': {
      return { ...state, inputValue: payload };
    }
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Import those into your provider file:

```
import { initialState, reducer } from './reducer';
```

and use `useReducer` to create a store:

```
export function WebContextProvider({ children }) {
  const store = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <WebContext.Provider value={store}>
      {children}
    </WebContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

You can then import the context into the component that needs it and use `useContext` to get at the state and dispatch method. On the click of the button you can dispatch a new value to the store to update `inputValue`.

```
export default function UpdateButton() {

  const [ { inputValue }, dispatch ] = useContext(WebContext);

  function handleClick(e) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'updateInputValue',
      payload: inputValue + 1
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{inputValue}</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I've created [a full demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-monad-wst3p) to show you how it works in harmony.